# Is Assist America a useful service?

Tags: discussion

Assist America is an emergency travel service offered through my company. I was wondering about experiences people have had with it and whether it's worthwhile to call them in an emergency, or just deal with it.

I'm not sure this question is on topic for this site, but not sure where else to find out this information.

Comment: hey Kevin, you probably want to put this on the main travel site, not the meta site, unless I'm mistaken in your intent? :/

Comment: I want to figure out whether it's on topic before posting to the main site.

Comment: What Phoenix said. Easiest is to [drop in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) and post your intention there if unsure. There are always people (and a few mods) that will be of assistance with on- or off-topicness. Often you'd get useful suggestions how to reformulate to bring your question more in line with site's FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

I've been tempted to post questions that I wasn't sure were on topic for the travel site quite a few times.

In every case, I decided to go ahead and post it anyway.

Each time, one of two things happened:

- While composing the question, I realized why it wasn't a very good fit for Travel.SE, or I discovered the answer myself, so I was able to abandon the question with a clear conscience.
- Or, I realized it probably was a good question, and I ended up getting [upvotes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5783/82) and [answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6503/82) beyond my wildest expectations (or at least within [two standard deviations thereof](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6499/82)).

In one case, [my question was closed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3802/82), but only after a friendly and objective comment-chat with a mod, and — surprisingly — life went on (:

The only exceptions to the above are the many expat questions I would love to ask, but those are [explicitly off-topic here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/328/82).